# Image onload, another error in IE - fairly sure it's not a caching error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onload

This code is the core of a much larger script that works great in almost all browsers. Yet it didn't work in IE. So I've stripped it down and found that the image.onload isn't firing in IE.

I've done some research, and I've guarded against it being an image caching problem. For one, the error occurs first time round before anything is cached, and, more importantly, the onload event is attached before the src.

I'm also reasonably sure I'm attaching the onload event in an IE compatible manner, so what gives, why don't I get an alert?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">             
            <script type="text/javascript">

        function generate(){
            var imageGen = document.createElement("img");
            imageGen.setAttribute('onload',"primer()"); 
            imageGen.setAttribute('src', "http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
            document.getElementById('image').appendChild(imageGen);
            }   

        function primer() { 
            alert("here now");
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="generate()">
        <div id="image">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**I'm hosting a version [here](http://thisisonlytemporary.co.uk/ed/tester.html)**

I only have access to IE8 unfortunately, so I don't know if it persists across other versions, even so it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, events are **not** attributes and must not be set using `setAttribute`. It might, or might not work.

Second, try creating image object instead of image element:

```
var imageGen = new Image();
imageGen.src = "http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
imageGen.onload = primer;
document.getElementById('image').appendChild(imageGen);
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/T7quE/) - worked fine for me on IE9 and IE9 compatibility mode which should be like IE8.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves everything perfectly. Out of interest, when should you create an element instead of an object?

Comment: @Olivier no problem! Not sure officially but I would say that whenever you have full scale object, it must be for a reason. Only other example I can think of right now is Option object but of course that when no such object exists, `document.createElement` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try imageGen.onload = primer instead of imageGen.setAttribute('onload',"primer()"); ?